# Defining angular modules in different files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I have 3 js files in my application
(`mainApp.js, template.js, app.js`)

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
```

mainApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', 
      ['myapp.templateApp', 'myapp.demoApp']);
```

template.js

```
angular.module('myapp.templateApp', ['slick', 'localization'])
.controller('CountryLaunguageSelection', [
    '$scope', '$rootScope','$http', 
    function($scope, $rootScope,$http) {

    }
]);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp.demoApp', [
              'ui.router',
              'ui.grid',
              'ngTouch',
              'ui.grid.selection',
              'ui.bootstrap',
              'ngTable'
          ]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

});
```

I need the 3 modules to be in 3 different files.Could anybody tell me what is wrong with the above code.

I am getting the below error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…0%2FdemoApp%2Ftemplate%2Fthird-party%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)
```

Comment: You did link all those files in your index file?

Comment: Yes i have linked those files.

Comment: Yes exactly as Rouby has said. Please load all of the js to the dom before injecting in a module. Like <script src="path/to/template.js"></script>.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainApp.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/template.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

Comment: @Nishashetty can you create simple jsfiddle of your problem, that would help us solving this better

Comment: load mainApp.js after these two js files

Comment: Did you include the other dependencies as well? ngTouch, ui-router, ui-grid, ui-bootstrap, ngTable?

Answer (score 0):

Just created such a localhost - it works. Try to compare your `index.html` and dependencies.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mainApp.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="template.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="CountryLaunguageSelection">
  {{data.myData}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mainApp.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['myapp.templateApp', 'myapp.demoApp']);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp.demoApp', []);

app.config(function() {

});
```

**template.js**

```
angular.module('myapp.templateApp', [])
  .controller('CountryLaunguageSelection', [
    '$scope', '$rootScope','$http',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
        $scope.data = {
          myData: "Hello"
        };
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Also check permissions to files if you work in Linux/MacOS. Sometimes it's needed to change `chown` and/or `chmode`